# Getting NA while converting date and time into Posixct for every 00:00:00 hour

Tags: r, lubridate, posixct, posixlt

I am trying to convert AM/PM formatted date and time into as.posixct , but for every 00:00:00 , i am getting NA. please guide me on this. please refer below image.[image]

**CODE I TRYED WITH FOR LOOP**

```
i=0
  for (i in 1:nrow(clean_df)){
  if((is.na(clean_df$Local_time)[i]) ==  TRUE){
  #cat("",clean_df$Local_time[i])
  clean_df$Local_time[i] <- paste("",as.Date(clean_df$Local_time[i-1]),"00:00:00")
  }
    print(nrow(clean_df)-i)

}
```

But above code is taking longer time to execute , which is not recommended . requesting you all any solution with this.

Comment: it will be good if you can provide reproducible example using dput()

Comment: @Hunaidkhan . No need to reproduce the code hardly one line code , it is pasted in the image and the code which I have tried I have shared .

Answer (score 2):

Given that some of your raw data may be lacking a time component, when you expect it to be present when converting to POSIXct, I don't see any way around scrubbing your data.  But, you may try doing the scrubbing in a vectorized way, which might perform better:

```
clean_df$Local_time <- ifelse(nchar(clean_df$Local_time) == 10,
                              paste(clean_df$Local_time, "00:00:00"),
                              clean_df$Local_time)
```